# Failed to read artifact desriptor for com.h2 database Spring MVC

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, h2

I want to set up a *com.h2database* in my project. In my pom.xml file, I am having a problem with the artifact descriptor.

code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>   <-------Here is problem
    <version>1.4.194</version>
</dependency>
```

Error:
[image: Screenshot of Error]

Output from Console:
[image: Screenshot of console output]

Comment: The version you have given `1.4.494` does not exist in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.h2database%22%20AND%20a%3A%22h2%22). So first I would suggest to use `1.4.193` instead.

Comment: @khmarbaise - thank you on your help, that is solution. Now I still have a problem, not same. http://prntscr.com/ejbhbn

Comment: @khmarbaise this is output  in console:  http://prntscr.com/ejbipj

Answer (score 2):

modify the version no 196 instead of 197, its working fine.